# How can i arrange data from two different columns?

Tags: excel

I have two columns `A` , `B`

```
A:have text
B:have values
```

I need to add the first value of `B` in first cell of Column `C` then, the next cell of column `C` have the first text of `A` and so on

EX:

```
C1:1234

C2:what is your name
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK... you aren't exactly clear on your question, since you can't have 2 cells in column C.  But I think what you want to do is write this formula in cell C2:

```
=B2 & " " & A2
```

That will put values from both columns A and B in the same cell, separated by a space.  But it's unclear what you want since "the first text of A and son on" could be interpreted many ways.

Please try the above formula and if it does not meet your demands then think of how you can rephrase your question.

----Edit----

In C1 enter the value:

```
=B1
```

In C2 enter the value:

```
=A1
```

Highlight both C1 and C2, then drag down with the fill handle.  That should do it.

Comment: ok i'm sorry for my unclear question . i'll post print screen of example of what i want . but are you vote me down ?

Comment: OK, answer is revised to address your example.